# Is this answer a form of undisclosed self-promotion

Tags: discussion, external-links

So I was looking to solve an issue when I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41725321/2357233).

The answer links to [this blog post](http://cordobo.com/2398-mysql-workbench-6-3-macos-sierra-hangs-on-simple-queries/) ([cached version for people who can't see it](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nu1jokJujQIJ:cordobo.com/2398-mysql-workbench-6-3-macos-sierra-hangs-on-simple-queries/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au)) at the end saying that the author got the solution from there. However at the end of the post, it says that the author discovered the solution using links that were provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41057208/2357233) to the question, and then also links directly back to the question.

The above coupled with the fact that the answer is relatively new (less than a week), when most of the other answers are from December last year, makes me wonder if there's more going on here than meets the eye. Now of course, the user profile in no way links to the website, that'd be too obvious. In fact, their SO profile is pretty much blank.

So is this just a user trying to increase traffic to their blog?

EDIT: Ok, maybe not, it's probably a lazy attempt to give their answer more credibility. I'll comment asking why there are circular links and see what happens.

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden when I try to browse to that link, so if this is spam, it failed.

Comment: @Cody Link works fine here (Firefox 50.1.0 Win)

Comment: Link works for me (Firefox 50.1.0 Mac)

Comment: Link's totally busted for me (Chrome 56 beta, Linux).  Besides that, do you have any concrete evidence to suggest that *they* owned the blog?

Comment: Odd. Fails for me in every browser I tested, including Safari and Chrome on OS X, and Waterfox on Windows. Since it doesn't work for Makoto either, and both of you guys are outside of the US, maybe it's a geographical thing?

Comment: Geo location or ISP blocking maybe? Works for me.

Comment: I've added a cached version. My main problem is that the text is identical in both locations. It just struck me as odd that's all. It's a circular reasoning fallacy. It's probably not self-promotion, probably an attempt to make their answer look more legit.

Comment: Alternative route without any kind of implied wrong doing: the link to the SO question was already there in the blog post, a reader of the blog post followed it and decided to post a new answer right there and then, linking back to the blog that they thought was excellent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see much self-promotion in there, unless you mean an attempt to get rep by writing an answer. No big deal.

An innocent explanation would be that the answerer didn't follow up the links in the blog post.

I would just put your findings as a comment under that first answer.